# SSRS Bar chart display data even when value is low

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

See image:
[image]

The orange item is always significantly lower than the blue item, but the orange colour on the graph is not displayed, is there any way of no matter how low the orange value, always have a small line of orange so that the user can clearly see which number is refering to the orange value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much easier and more elegant way to do this (at least in SSRS 2008 R2). I am not sure what is available in SSRS 2008 or 2005.

For the axis you want to show small values,

- Set `CrossAt` and `Minimum` properties to a negative number, large enough to display on the report.
- Set the `IntervalOffset` property to the same number, but positive.

This will make the other axis of the report be below 0, so that a very low (or even 0) value will still show a small amount of color. The negative value you choose and the max value of the chart will determine how large this color slice is.

Here is an example of this technique to show a small amount of color for 0%:

[image: bar chart with 0% showing]

If you leave out the `CrossAt` property, then the bars float away from the y-axis, leaving a gap. You must use all the properties I mentioned above to make the color reach past 0 all the way to the axis line.

Important note: the chart in design mode will NOT show correctly. It will display a negative number starting the x-axis instead of 0, but don't believe your eyes. When you actually preview the report, the result will be correct. Don't let yourself be thrown off by the design-mode pre-preview!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways around this that I've used depending on what mattered most to the end user:

1) Increment the data bar by 1% of the maximum value - i.e. Field B + (MAX(Fields!a.value) / 100) and then make sure the data label shows Field B's Value only so that the data bar will not be 100% accurate but the label will be.

2) Plot field B's data on a secondary axis and then fix the maximum to be a proportion of the maximum field A value.

Both of these rely on there not being an axis with values included, but the values being derived from the labels themselves.

3) Format the data labels for the bars to have either a blue / orange font or blue / orange fill - this is most useful when you need to retain the values on the axes. You can then use conditional formatting to only colour the label if the value is too small to show in the bar (i.e < 1% of the maximum chart value).

Personally I would recommend option 3) as there can be issues surrounding manipulating data bar length if another developer comes along later!

Answer (score 1):

1) Store the MAX value in your chart to a variable (nChartMaxVal).

2) Create a function to place on you CHART whereever the value references occur:

pseudocode:

```
SubstValueNegligableValue( pValue, nChartMaxVal) as Double
                If pValue < (nChartMaxVal / 10) then

                    pValue = nChartMacVal / 10    'Sets Value to 10% of MaxChartValue'

                Endif

                Return pValue
```

3) pValue should be the Chart Value you want to evaluate.

Hope this guides you along.

If you are using a stored proc then you can build this logic in there and return the adjusted value where applicable. I would suggest having a flag returned by tthe proc though that says if the substitution has been made so that you can automate a comment on your report somewhere that tells the user viewing the chart that a substitution has been made.

See Davins input above regarding the conditional formatting. this will be useful in indocating the substitute values from the genuine one. I.e. maybe crosshatch the substitute value in the same color to show a difference.

Cheers

Mac